# Apache solr coverting to xml

Tags: solr

I am learning how to use solr but I am struck at a point how to upload a .txt format book to solr I know I need to convert in to XML format but I dont know How to or how format looks like can some one explain me in step by step process

Answer (score 0):

in order to avoid creating the input doc in xml format yourself, you could use tika request handler (it extracts text form various formats including plain text), see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler)